# Unable to install Valgrind to OS X

Tags: mac, mac-osx, valgrind

I [downloaded](http://valgrind.org/downloads/current.html#current) the newest Valgrind and extracted it.

I run

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/valgrind
make
```

which gives me

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

I run

```
make install
```

It gives me

```
make: Nothing to be done for `install'.
```

**How can you install Valgrind to the newest OS X?**

Comment: Did you `cd` into the newly created directory? You have to be in the directory after you extract it to run those commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version 3.4.1 is incompatible with Mac OS X as far as I know. As it wasn't until more recently (May 2009 - 3.4.1 was released in February 2009) that valgrind was given "[compatibility](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/valgrind/)." The Mac OS X port is as quoted from the Mac OS X page:

> This port is **UNSUPPORTED** and **INCOMPLETE** and **BUGGY**

You'll need to get the latest from svn as documented on [valgrind.org](http://valgrind.org/downloads/repository.html):

```
svn co svn://svn.valgrind.org/valgrind/trunk valgrind
cd valgrind
./autogen.sh
./configure --prefix=...
make
make install
```

You will need `autoconf` and `automake` as well that can be most easily installed using [MacPorts](http://macports.org)

For debugging the "configure, make, make install" dance:

Did you see what error in the `configure` phase came up? You can't `make` (and subsequently install using `make install`) unless the configuration works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The [instructions](http://valgrind.org/downloads/repository.html) say you need to do `./autogen.sh` before `make`.